# Modeling database using associative tables vs hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

When modeling entities, what would be some reasons against modeling all relationships as associative entities as opposed to using a more hierarchical structure. For example, consider two tables `container` and `item`

Option A (parent-child, 1:many):

```
create table container (
    id    int   identity(1,1) primary key,
)

create table item (
    id          int  identity(1,1) primary key,
    containerId int  references container(id)
)
```

Option B (associative table, 1:many)

```
create table container (
    id    int   identity(1,1) primary key,
)

create table item (
    id    int  identity(1,1) primary key,        
)

create table container_items (
    containerId int  references container(id),
    itemId      int  references item(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (itemId)        
)
```

Both structures achieve the same outcome, but offer us different characteristics.

Option A is what would be the more traditional way of modeling the relationship, and provides us with item data when we get the row result.

Option B requires us to create an extra index to achieve our constraints, and will require an extra join to get the item details. On the other hand, it decouples our item entity from our container, and we can now associate it with other entities without needing a reference to a container id. We also have the structure in place to easily convert to a many:many table if that need arises.

Designing around option B allows us to model all our entities at the root level, and easily form cross-associations. This kind of design seems to be well suited for use with web libraries such as redux, which benefit from normalized JSON.

What other pros/cons might option B offer?

Comment: All relational modeling is "using associative tables". Relational tables represent relation(ship)s/associations. FKs are not needed to query, do not add anything to what the tables say about the current situation, and just tell the DBMS that only certain states will turn up, so it can reject impossible updates. "Hierarchy" is just a way of describing a relation(ship)s/association that is acyclic. That includes hierarchies expressed by the data & meta-hierarchies like "there is a FK between" expressed by certain metadata. These terms are not being used meaningfully in expressing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Option A you're intentionally limiting the relationship (one to many) and in Option B if your intention is to use it in a "one to many" format you're opening up the possibility of data integrity errors. This is because in Option B a "many to many" relationship is achievable (and the primary reason for having an associative table in a relational database). Plus if you have no need for an associative table in a true "one to many" relationship you're simply costing yourself querying speed/resources for no reason.

However, there is a potential reason I can think of that you may want to accept that risk in a "one to many" relationship... if in the associative table you have additional columns that relate specifically to that particular relationship between the two tables (container and item).

For example.... 'Container 1' may have a relationship to 'Item A' and 'Item B'. However, quantity is an additional column in which you provide for on the associative table. So you can now properly persist that data such that the associative table maintains two rows in this case:

**id - container_name**

1 - Container 1

**id - item_name**

1 - Item A

2 - Item B

**container_id - item_id - quantity**

1 *(Container 1)* - 1 *(Item A)* - 2

1 *(Container 1)* - 3 *(Item B)* - 4

Answer (score 1):

Long story short:

**Option A**

This is the design you should implement for "one-to-many" relationships

**Option B**

As mentioned by ThatTechGuy, this is the design you should implement for "many-to-many" relationships.

I would not recommend to use option B if you only have a parent-child (one-to-many) relationship. When you have an associate table (aka intersection table) SQL queries are more troublesome to write (you need 2 joins to build your hierarchy) and it can also impact performances on big volumes of data.